# A=B.C if C is non-singular then col(A)=col(B)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A,B,C be matrices such that A=B.C

if C is non-singular, then col(A)=col(B).

is this the case?

Comment: yes, it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is true. All you need to show is that $col(B)=col(BC)$ for $C$ invertible.

"$col(BC)\subseteq col(B)$":

Let $x \in col(BC)$.

$\exists y$ such that $BCy=x$.

Relabel $Cy$ as $y'$.

$\therefore By'=x$

$\therefore x \in col(B)$

"$col(B)\subseteq col(BC)$":

Let $x \in col(B)$.

$\exists y$ such that $By=x$.

$\because C$ is invertible, $\exists z$ s.t $Cz=y$.

$\therefore BCz=x$

$\therefore x \in col(BC)$

$\therefore col(B)=col(BC)=col(A)$ :)

Comment: If A=CB for C invertible, then the result is false. Consider A=<1,0;0,0>, B=<1,0;1,0>, C=<1,0;1/2,-1/2>. Then A=CB but col(A) is not equal to col(B). Here <a,b;c,d> refers to $ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d  \\
\end{array} \right)$

Answer (score 1):

Yes

Think of $C$ as instructions for how to write the columns of $A = BC$ as linear combinations of the columns of $B$.  This shows you that the column space of $A$ is contained in the column space of $B$.  Now since $C$ in nonsingular it's invertible so we can write $B = AC^{-1}$ and conclude the converse, that the column space of $B$ is contained in the column space of $A$, hence they're equal.